# How to pass value as string in ForeignKey and not integer?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

[IMPORT PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X45cO.png)

I tried to import my model in admin to csv file and the output of the foreignkeys are integers(see Department and Status fields in photo above). How can i convert that into string?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question! How and where are you importing the .csv file? What do you mean when you say that the output of your foreignkeys are integers? What output are you expecting, and what output did you get instead? Why is it that you are having a problem with output if you are attempting to perform an import?

Comment: Hello Sam, thank you for commenting. I mean my model has values, i tried to export in in the admin panel using import_export library. The output on the excel file for the fields which are foreignkeys are integers as you see in the 'IMPORT PHOTO', photo. What i expect to have there are string and not integer(e.g. ACCOUNTING,HR, etc.)

Comment: Can you share the code of your admin.py?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hG1MTln

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how to add relationship fields [the documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting-data). It suggests adding two classes: a resource class to define which fields are exported and an admin class that connects the resource class to the admin interface. In your case `admin.py` may look like

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources

class HrmResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = hrm
        fields = ('name', 'place', 'department__nm_dept')

class HrmAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = HrmResource

admin.site.register(r_dept)
admin.site.register(hrm, HrmAdmin)
```

and `models.py` like

```
from django.db import models

class r_dept(models.Model):
    nm_dept = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nm_dept

class hrm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department = models.ForeignKey('r_dept')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Hi Zbynek, thanks for commenting. I tried to replicate that.  the now the import/export is not showing?  https://imgur.com/a/urkG4cy. sorry, im new...

Comment: @JonathanChiong I added all the necessary code to the example, hope it helps.

Comment: It worked!!! it was confusing for me at first coz both fields in these 2 class im working on has same name. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The code above does not support import: the `id` of the hrm records is not exported and `department_id` is not directly present in the CSV (`department__nm_dept` is rread only). You can just add those two missing fields to the `fields` list.